# Can anyone identify these mushrooms?

Tags: species-identification, mycology

Found in the Dolomites, Italy

1. in a wooden fence: [image: first mushroom]
2. [image: second mushroom]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is dyer's polypore or rusty gilled polypore.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gloeophyllum_sepiarium

The second one looks a bit like orange peel fungus, although it could be something different.
https://www.wildfooduk.com/mushroom-guide/orange-peel-fungus/

Comment: Thank you! The second one is really similar to an orange peel fungus, unfortunately I did not take more photo that might have helped with identification...